# Create a launcher for Kile built from source?

Tags: launcher, kile

I just installed the LaTeX editor Kile from source on my Ubuntu 10.04 with KDE (I know it is also available in the package-manager, however if you install it from there it will install TeXLive 2009 which I don't want).

The documentation of Kile says:

> You can start Kile with the following
>   command:

```
KDEDIRS=$HOME/kile-install:$KDEDIRS $HOME/kile-install/bin/kile
```

This works fine, however it would be much more convenient to have this as a symbol-launcher on my workspace desktop.

How can I create a launcher from this command given above so that I can start Kile with a double-click on an icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally familiar with KDE, but I know it's underlying launcher/menu system is the same as GNOME, Xfce4, etc.  To make a launcher for any program (anything, really) make an empty text file and put this in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=
GenericName=
Comment=
Exec=
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=
```

This is a skeleton launcher file.  You can see examples in the /usr/share/applications directory.  Just fill it in accordingly:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Kile
GenericName=LaTeX Editor
Comment=This is a menu tool tip if you want one
Exec=KDEDIRS=$HOME/kile-install:$KDEDIRS $HOME/kile-install/bin/kile
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/path/to/your/kile/icon
Categories=These are the menu categories if you wanted it in the menu, but not necessary for just a launcher.
```

Now save the file as `kile.desktop`

Now make the file executable.  Once executable the file will change.  It should now appear as the icon and name you chose rather than "kile.desktop".  Double click it and your program should open.

Since you are using paths and such in your Exec= field things may not work correctly.  I don't know since I've never tried.  This would be easily remedied if it doesn't, so just let me know.

Hope that was helpful.

EDIT: I see that it failed to execute.  I can think of 2 simple fixes.  The easiest is to make the Exec= field look like this:

```
Exec=sh -c "KDEDIRS=$HOME/kile-install:$KDEDIRS $HOME/kile-install/bin/kile"
```

That should work.  Another way, is to create a shell script.  Make a blank text file and put this in it:

```
#!bin/bash
KDEDIRS=$HOME/kile-install:$KDEDIRS $HOME/kile-install/bin/kile
```

Save it as "kile.sh" or whatever, and make it executable.  Now you ought to be able to launch Kile directly by executing the file, or you can add the path to kile.sh to your launcher file's Exec= field:

```
Exec=/path/to/kile.sh
```

Also, if you put kile.sh in your $PATH, such as ~/bin, you'll be able to launch Kile by typing `kile.sh` in a terminal rather than the long command.

If none of that works then I have made a typo :)

Comment: Thank you but unfortunatelly this does not work and exits with the Error: Failes to execute child process "KDEDIRS=$HOME...." (no such file or directory)

Comment: A work-around that I found is to link to the file in /kile-install/bin/kile but this is some sort of executable and can't be opened with an editor. I would still be interested in a solution with the launcher

Comment: I have edited my answer.  Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: If linking to the /kile-install/bin/kile file works without needing the other stuff simply add that as your Exec= field rather than the long command.

Comment: Thank you very much. The change to EXEC=sh - c... did it. I haven't tried the appraoch with the sh file, but I can't see why this shouldn't work.

Comment: Your welcome.  The shell script is essentially the same thing.  The "sh -c" is basically just passing the command to your shell, as if you were running the command in a terminal but without actually opening a terminal.  Very useful for many things!

Comment: these only make kile open but don't call up latex engine. you can edit but not compile